# Rasa: Conflict between regex entiity extractor and dietClassifier

Tags: nlp, entity, chatbot, rasa, rasa-core

I have two entity named entity1 and entity2 
entity1 consists of examples like "abc" "def" "xyz" 
entity2 consists of examples like "abc/123" "def/325"

But regex entity extractor is extracting abc from abc/123 and storing it in entity1 slot instead of storing entire abc/123 in entity2 slot and diet classifier is being overriden by regex entity extractor.

I have added lot of training examples, but still result is same.

Comment: Sorry, what is the question?